# Dockerize multiple app in nx monorepo doesn't work

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nx-monorepo

Hi i have 3 apps in my nx monorepo:

1.React-app

2.post-retrieval-service

3.post-management-service

also a DockerFile in the root of project:

```js
FROM node:18-alpine3.18

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .
```

and a docker-compose.base.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  nx-app-base:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - DEV_PLATFORM=DOCKER
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - mono-node-modules:/app/node_modules
```

and a docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  # React App
  react:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: nx-app-base
    command: npx nx serve web
    ports:
      - 4200:4200

  # Post-retrieval Service
  post-retrieval:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: nx-app-base
    command: npx nx serve services-post-retrieval-service
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  # Post-management Service
  post-management:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: nx-app-base
    command: npx nx serve services-post-management-service
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    depends_on:
      - mongo


  # mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongodb/mongodb-community-server:latest
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin

volumes:
  mono-node-modules: null
```

when i execute docker-compose up --build in the terminal, everything is good and containers run currectly, but when i try to open http://localhost:4200 in my browser, i face to an error that it is "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

also when i get logs for react app, there is no error, but about post-* apps there is an error about connecting to mongo is failed.

I have [a screen shot of the Docker Desktop application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ajkh.png) showing all of the containers in "running" status.

Comment: So `react` tries to connect to `localhost:3001` and/or `3000`? That is *your* localhost. Try setting `network_mode` to `host` in your docker-compose.yml and see if it resolve the issue. This is not a solution, just a workaround and a quick hack to see if this is the only problem.

Comment: No, react serve on localhost:4200

Comment: @doneforaiur it didn't work with network_mode

Comment: Is `connecting to mongo is failed` resolved?

Comment: @doneforaiur yes, but the react app does not depend on mongodb

Comment: We cannot know for sure why it's returning an empty response without seeing the `react` code. It does return but it doesn't send anything. Check this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65881054/neterr-empty-response-when-api-request-is-made-in-return-of-react and apart from this check if you are correctly returning a value. To test this, make a dummy endpoint that will return `200, "success"` or something on `GET` request.

Comment: but my issue isn't a console error, infact when i try to open this address in my browser i recieve this error from browser: localhost didn't send any data

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. In fact, the reason for not receiving a response on port `4200`, which is specific to my React app, was that I used the command `npx nx serve web`, which takes some time to serve the app for me.

Additionally, the issue of my apps not connecting to `MongoDB` was due to the fact that I needed to change the value of the ***host*** from `localhost` to the `container name` where MongoDB was running. I performed this change through a .env file so that I could modify the host value to my desired value in the Docker environment. Finally, my files looked like this:

**dataSource.ts:**

```
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
import { Post } from '../entity';
const host = process.env.MONGO_HOST || 'localhost'
const dbConfig: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'mongodb',
  host,
  port: 27017,
  database: 'admin',
  authSource: 'admin',
  entities: [Post],
  synchronize: true,
};

export const dataSource = new DataSource({ ...dbConfig });
```

and ***docker-compose.yml***:

```
version: '3'

services:
  # React App
  react:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: nx-app-base
    command: npx nx serve web --host=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 4200:4200

  # Post-retrieval Service
  post-retrieval:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: nx-app-base
    command: npx nx serve services-post-retrieval-service  --host=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=mongo
      - HOST=0.0.0.0

  # Post-management Service
  post-management:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: nx-app-base
    command: npx nx serve services-post-management-service --host=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=mongo
      - HOST=0.0.0.0

  # mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongodb/mongodb-community-server:latest
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin

volumes:
  mono-node-modules: null
```