# Docker does not forward ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose

`docker-compose.yml` is:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  # React App
  react:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: nx-app-base
    command: npx nx serve web --host=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 4200:4200

  # Post-retrieval Service
  post-retrieval:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: nx-app-base
    command: npx nx serve services-post-retrieval-service --host=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=mongo

  # Post-management Service
  post-management:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: nx-app-base
    command: npx nx serve services-post-management-service --host=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=mongo


  # mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongodb/mongodb-community-server:latest
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin

volumes:
  mono-node-modules: null
```

All containers create and start successfully and there are no errors in their logs. React app runs in my browser on `localhost:4200` but I cant open `post-retrieval-service` and `post-management-service` on `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3001`. They work through curl in their terminal but it seems docker couldn't forward their ports.

How can I fix them?

Comment: This seems like essentially the same setup and the same symptom as [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593742/dockerize-multiple-app-in-nx-monorepo-doesnt-work); how is it different?

Comment: No, but in this time, port was forwarded for react app but about 2 other apps was not.

Comment: They need to have the same network defined in order to communicate with each other. The port forwarding is to forward from your local machine to the container.

Comment: This is a case where you should [edit your earlier question](/posts/76593742/edit) and not ask a new one as the history and the greater details (e.g. Dockerfiles...) will help people troubleshoot your issue and prevent them from offering solutions that were already proposed. Also please have a look at the edit which were made on both questions as this one suffered from the same layout problems (which I corrected) that @DavidMaze had already fixed in your other one (i.e. simple code blocks vs snippets which no one can run). Thanks.

Comment: @GabeRAMturn All of the containers are on the Compose-provided `default` network.  Typical Compose applications do not need `networks:` at all.  See the linked previous question for the contents of `docker-compose.base.yml`, and [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for more details on the `default` network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I found the solution to the problem. I needed to provide a .env file for two services, "post-retrieval-service" and "post-management-service," which I developed using Express.js. This .env file should contain the hostname so that I can change the hostname from localhost to 0.0.0.0 in the Docker environment. I did this, and Docker was able to easily forward the port for me. In essence, my docker-compose file looked like this:

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'

services:
  # React App
  react:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: nx-app-base
    command: npx nx serve web --host=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 4200:4200

  # Post-retrieval Service
  post-retrieval:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: nx-app-base
    command: npx nx serve services-post-retrieval-service  --host=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=mongo
      - HOST=0.0.0.0

  # Post-management Service
  post-management:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: nx-app-base
    command: npx nx serve services-post-management-service --host=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=mongo
      - HOST=0.0.0.0

  # mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongodb/mongodb-community-server:latest
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin

volumes:
  mono-node-modules: null
```